# ROR: Validate Non-model fields in model file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some fields in my form that are not part of the model, I know how to validate those fields in the controller, but I was wondering if it is possible to validate this in the model?

If it is possible, how would I validate next?
e.g.

```
text_field(nil, :non_model_field)
```

Comment: Validations don't care if a value is persisted or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

put a virtual attribute in the model.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base

   attr_accessor :non_model_field
   validates :non_model_field, presence: true # or whatever other validations you want

end
```

Comment: I did tried that, but the rails form throws the error that the non_model_field can't be blank even if I enter an string as an input.

Comment: if you remove the validation: `presence:true`, does it raise the error `field can't be blank`? it sounds like it picked up the validation but not recognizing the `string input`

Comment: I tried but I have to add "length: {minimum: 1}" because the validates line must have at least one condition, but it says that "non_model_filed is too short (minimum is 1 characters)", I looks that it is not receiving the string as input.  :s

Answer (score 2):

As `@wali Ali` mentioned, you'll need to use a virtual attribute using the [`attr_accessor`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor) method to create non-persistent data

This method works by creating relevant `getter` & `setter` methods for your model, which basically create a series of attributes you can use on your model object. These attributes can then be validated, even if they are not saved, by your model:

```
#app/models/model.rb
Class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :test, :attribute #-> creates @model.test & @model.attribute
    validates :test, :attribute, presence: true
end
```